# How to get checked items in a WPF ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF ListBox where I have checkboxes, but what's the way to get the list of items that are checked?

The ListBox is data binded to a `Dictionary<T>`.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Nodes}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" x:Name="MyList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Name" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Id" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Name="NodeItem" Click="OnItemChecked">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Value.Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="-" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Value.Id}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have an example of how to easily make a Checked Listbox in WPF http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/ if you use a wrapper such as that it is easy to tell which items are checked by looking at the collection and testing the IsChecked property.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done through a ViewModel, that is a data structure that exposes to the view (through the DataContext) both the model (your data) and view-specific information, like whether an item is checked or not.

In your example, your Dictionary would not be, say, a Dictionary, but a Dictionary and the PersonViewModel would have a IsChecked property and a Person property pointing to the model.

Otherwise, you have to go and find the checkbox in templates or get to the list box item from the checkbox and this gets complex pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks this is useful. But how do you so this in code? Do you have any examples or links?

Comment: I agree with @VoidDweller on the link. Another link (also an article from Josh Smith) is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. Specifically about IsChecked, have a look at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/treeview/getting-checked-items-using-mvvm.aspx, where they put ViewModel properties the model, but the idea is the same.

Comment: The MSDN article is a good one. I like the forum link, class diagrams are great. I also added the Jason Dolinger link to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Josh Smith has an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) on codeproject that should explain what you need. He is discussing a `TreeView` but the principle will port over to the `CheckBox` as well.

There is also a very interesting approach [here](http://goalbook.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/wpf-checkedlist-control/) using a `DataTemplate` and Binding the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property to the `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` property.

If you are new to MVVM, [Jason Dolinger](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) has an excellent video on the subject. It steps you through the process moving from using code behind files to a full MVVM pattern including Dependency Injection and Testing.