# How to explicitly select the row in ListView in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, binding

I have a ListView in which one of the column contains combo box.

I have binded the selectedItem of a Listview, so that I get the current object (selected row  ) in the listview.

When I do any operation in a combo box like selection change then the listview row ( in which that combo box belongs) is not selected be default and hence my selectedItem gives null or previous row selected object.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is closely related to [WPF ListView SelectedItem is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608187/wpf-listview-selecteditem-is-null/2608315#2608315)