# WPF: Checkbox in a ListView/Gridview--How to Get ListItem in Checked/Unchecked Event?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

In the code behind's CheckBox_Checked and CheckBox_Unchecked events, I'd like to be able to access the item in MyList that the checkbox is bound to.

Is there an easy way to do this?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="100">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn>                            
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Margin="-4,0,-4,0" IsChecked="{Binding MyBoolProperty}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CheckBox.DataContext` property will hold the bound item.

Comment: @Phil: To be precise, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608187/wpf-listview-selecteditem-is-null/2608315#2608315

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get access to the object that the CheckBox is bound to, or the actual `ListBoxItem` that is used in the UI? If you just want the object the CheckBox is bound to, then @Charlie 's answer will work. Otherwise, you can call [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx) until you reach the `ListBoxItem`.