# WPF Listview & Checkboxes - Binding issue when using relative source

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, wcf-binding

I have a listview with two columns, one contains a textbox and the other a checkbox. These are bound to an ObservableCollection of a custom object containing a string for the textbox and a boolean for the checkbox.

All was working well until I tried having the check event of the checkbox highlight it's the row in the listview as in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608187/wpf-listview-selecteditem-is-null/2608315#2608315).

My problem is that checkbox no longer binds to the ObservableCollection. The textbox binds okay, but changing the checbox declaration from:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RestrictedEdit}"/>
```

to this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RestrictedEdit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"/>
```

stops the checkbox binding and the listview is displayed with the checkboxes all unchecked irrespectivate of status of the boolean. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to bind to `RestrictedEdit` property, which `ListViewItem` doesn't have. This property is declared in view model, which is stored in `DataContext`, so this should work:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.RestrictedEdit,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                              AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"/>
```

However, I don't see any reason to use this code instead of simple `IsChecked="{Binding RestrictedEdit}"`. `CheckBox` inherits `DataContext` from `ListViewItem`, so there is no reason to use relative source.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. I've looked over several articles on doing what I want and it looks like I've got a couple of the examples mixed up. That's working perfectly now plus I understand how the relative bindings work, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Let the binding as it is (no RelativeSource) and use rather a style or a DataTemplate having your custom object class as TargetType, and with a DataTrigger set on RestrictedEdit.
example with style :

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="MyClass">
  <Setter Property="BackGround" Value="White" />
  <Style.Trigger>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RestrictedEdit}" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="BackGround" Value="Gray" />
      </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Trigger>
</Style>
```

Define this style, say, in your application resources (in App.xaml).
Then in your listview, use :

```
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"
```