# How To Access WebControl in a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to set a value for `TextLabel` when the the `LinkButton` MessageName is clicked. However I'm not having any luck.

I tried using `DataList.SelectedItem.FindControl("blah")` as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.selecteditem.aspx) but `SelectedItem` keeps returning `null`.

I also tried something like [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608187/wpf-listview-selecteditem-is-null) but it's not working as well.

```
<asp:DataList
   ID="dlMessages"
   runat="server"
   DataSourceID="dsMessages">
<EditItemStyle Font-Names="Courier New" />
<ItemStyle BorderStyle="NotSet" />
<ItemTemplate>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="MessageName" Text="Some stuff" runat="server" /></td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Label ID="TextLabel" runat="server />
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>

 protected void DataList_OnItemCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (dlMessages.SelectedItem == null)
         return;
     DagSelect.Text = ((LinkButton) dlMessages.SelectedItem.FindControl("MessageName")).Text;
     Label l = (Label) dlMessages.SelectedItem.FindControl("TextLabel");
     l.Text = DagSelect.Text;
 }
```

Does anyone know a good way to do this? Basically, I only want the text to be displayed when the item is selected. When it's not, the string should remain empty/invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `CommandName="Select"` to your LinkButton, then change your event to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on your DataList.

```
<asp:LinkButton CommandName="Select" ID="MessageName" Text="Some stuff" runat="server" />
```